# How to fix wrapping elements inside BoxInsetLayout nested in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, scroll, wear-os

I want to achive **scrollable** BoxInsetlayout with child boxed from top, and sides. Wrapping component inside child of ScrollView-nested BoxInsetLayout seems to be buggy. Is this because BoxInsentLayout can't be set for wrap-content?

Here's my example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:boxedEdges="left|top|right" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Result:
[image: result]

Expectation:
[image: ![expectiation](https://ibb.co/vjPPmZR)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for that was adding: `android:fillViewport="true"`.